# Cannot run docker from network mounted directory

Tags: docker, ubuntu

When I try to run `docker version` in Ubuntu 20, and the path is pointing to an nfs mounted directory I get the message: *cannot open path of the current working directory: Permission denied*. My other applications run fine from the same path. I have a group `docker` and I am a member of it. Working from my local home directory is ok. The `docker version` output run from home:

```
(base) user@host:~
$ docker version
Client:
 Version:           18.09.9
 API version:       1.39
 Go version:        go1.13.4
 Git commit:        1752eb3
 Built:             Sat Nov 16 01:05:26 2019
 OS/Arch:           linux/amd64
 Experimental:      false

Server:
 Engine:
  Version:          18.09.9
  API version:      1.39 (minimum version 1.12)
  Go version:       go1.13.4
  Git commit:       9552f2b
  Built:            Sat Nov 16 01:07:48 2019
  OS/Arch:          linux/amd64
  Experimental:     false
```

And from a mounted directory:

```
(base) user@host:/media/i
$ docker version
cannot open path of the current working directory: Permission denied
```

My nfs (v4) mounts are in `/media`: `/media/i`, `/media/m`, etc. When I `cd /media` and next run `docker version` all is fine but when I `cd /media/i` I get the permission denied error. Permission for `/media` is `drwxr-xr-x` and for `/media/i`: `drwxrwxrwx`, `root:root` as owner in both cases. When I try `sudo docker version` results are identical.

I cannot see what I am doing wrong. Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It appeared to be an installation problem. I originally used snap to install docker:

```
sudo snap install docker
```

I removed this package and tried:

```
sudo apt install docker.io
```

Since then docker works from a network mount as well. Never use snap when you have an apt alternative, or so it seems.

**Edit**

I had a similar experience using visual code. The question was answered in more detail at [the ubuntu forum](https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2443712&p=13958815#post13958815) and is indeed a snap problem. Also a solution is offered if one wants/needs to continue the snap version.